# Removing the dash from both ends of a pattern using Regex

Tags: notepad++, hdmi, regex, video-editing, vb.net

I want to remove the dash from both ends of a pattern `-L-07-TV-04-Clip-01-` using Regex.

```
-L-07-TV-04-Clip-01-  
-I-have-to-realize-  
-me-having-this-addiction-  
-END-OF-CLIP-  
-L-07-TV-04-Clip-02-  
-I-have-to-realize-  
-when-I-felt-anger-  
-END-OF-CLIP-  
-L-07-TV-04-Clip-03-  
-I-have-to-realize-  
-when-I-have-shamed-others-  
-END-OF-CLIP-  
-L-07-TV-04-Clip-04-  
-I-have-to-realize-  
-when-I-have-shamed-myself-  
-END-OF-CLIP-  
-L-07-TV-04-Clip-05-  
-I-have-to-realize-  
-I-need-to-accept-  
-END-OF-CLIP-
```

The expected formatting is:

- Before Regex -L-07-TV-04-Clip-01-
- After Regex L-07-TV-04-Clip-01

Comment: What is your question. The title is not the question. The body needs more than just your data.

Comment: ... and an example of the original text with correct line breaks (see formatting rules) and the expected result.

Comment: That is the correct formatting: Before Regex -L-07-TV-04-Clip-01- After Regex L-07-TV-04-Clip-01

Comment: Welcome to Super User! For future use only because I did this for you in this one case - please [edit] your question to add some explanation or code instead of using comments as you did. Please read [ask] a good question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have your clip titles in a text file line by line you'd go through following steps (quick and dirty solution):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(^-)(L-07-TV-04-Clip-[0-9]{2})(-$)`
- Replace with: `$2`
- Search mode: Regular expression
- Click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

results in:

[image]

Comment: Wonderful Thanks I needed to update it, to work on other TV-00, using what was provided (^-)(L-01-TV-[0-9]{2}-Clip-[0-9]{2})(-$)

Comment: @HHH-Messenger - Your welcome. If it was helpful please accept the answer and upvote.